# While using string.count() method I am getting an error, TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Tags: python, count

```
s = "That that is is that that is not is not is that it it"
sub = "s"
print "str.count(sub, 4, 40) : ", str.count(sub, 4, 40)
```

While using `string.count()` method getting the following error.

Error :

```
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Comment: You need `s.count(sub, 4, 40)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call the method on the str class but on your string object:

```
s = "That that is is that that is not is not is that it it"
sub = "s"
print "s.count(sub, 4, 40) : ", s.count(sub, 4, 40)
```